# Can't run Toplevel window

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, toplevel

I am new to python and Tkinter and I need some help. I try to write a program which will show toplevel window with message on defined time. I introduce date, hour and text to program. Press "START" button and wait until toplevel window with message appear. 
Program work when I do not use thread, but main window "freeze" until loop is done. Then new toplevel window appear with text.

What I would like to do is to get rid of "freezing" main window. My idea was to use thread for loop executing. But it does not work. When loop is finished in a thread it should call function which cause to Toplevel window appear. But it does not. Moreover program freeze.

I know that I should not use thread within tkinter mainloop but I can not figure out how in other way I can get rid of "freezing" main window.

thank you for all your answers.

Rafal

here is my program:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import calendar
import datetime
import thread

class Okienka(object):
    def __init__(self, master):

    self.rok = Label(master, text = "Podaj rok: ")
    self.rok.grid(row = 0, sticky = E)
    self.miesiac = Label(master, text = "Podaj miesiac w formacie XX: ")
    self.miesiac.grid(row = 1, sticky = E)
    self.dzien = Label(master, text = "Podaj dzien w formacie XX: ")
    self.dzien.grid(row = 2, sticky = E)
    self.godzina = Label(master, text = "Podaj godzine w formacie XX:XX: ")
    self.godzina.grid(row = 3, sticky = E)
    self.przyp = Label(master, text = "Tekst przypomnienia: ")
    self.przyp.grid(columnspan = 2)

    self.erok = Entry(master, width = 4)
    self.erok.grid(row = 0 ,column = 1)
    self.emiesiac = Entry(master, width = 2)
    self.emiesiac.grid(row = 1 ,column = 1)
    self.edzien = Entry(master, width = 2)
    self.edzien.grid(row = 2 ,column = 1)
    self.egodzina = Entry(master, width = 5)
    self.egodzina.grid(row = 3 ,column = 1)
    self.eprzyp = Text(master, width = 50, heigh = 10, font = ("Helvetica",10))
    self.eprzyp.grid(columnspan = 2)

    self.button1 = Button(master, text = "START", fg = "red", command = watek)
    self.button1.grid(columnspan = 2)

def watek():
    thread.start_new_thread(Czas,())

def Czas():
    data = "{0}-{1}-{2} {3}".format(c.erok.get(), c.emiesiac.get(), c.edzien.get(), c.egodzina.get())

    while True:
        aktualny_czas = datetime.datetime.today()
        czas_str = time.strftime(str(aktualny_czas))
        czas_str = czas_str[:16]
        print  czas_str

        if data == czas_str:        
            okienko()   
        break

def okienko():
        komunikat = c.eprzyp.get("1.0","end-1c")        
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("Przypomnienie")
        msg = Message(top, text = komunikat)
        msg.pack()      

root = Tk()
c = Okienka(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the root window in a Tkinter application actually means destroying (freezing) the whole [application](http://www.usa-it-company.com), not only the root window. The root window is the main
window for the application; it is the first to pop up and must be the last to
go. If I understand correctly, your application does not have an actual main
window: if a second window is opened from the initial window, closing the
initial window should not quit the application. Am I right?

If I am, the way to do that with Tkinter (or tcl/tk) is to create a fake root
window and hide it. This window will only be used to quit the application when
the last window is closed:

Comment: I do not realy get what you mean. I tryed destroing root in function which call toplevel window and I got some results (two empty windows appeard :/ and application died). In general, the idea is to let loop work in backgroud after pushing button "START". When loop is done popup window appear with message which was defined in main window.